# Insert binary data from textbox to column

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

Can please some one tell me how I can insert data from textbot in SQL database but in binary format. Here is a part of my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=" + File.ReadAllText("Server.ini") + ";" + "Initial Catalog=" + "lin2db" + ";" + "User ID=" + File.ReadAllText("User.ini") + ";" + "Password=" + File.ReadAllText("Password.ini");
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO server (id, name, ip, inner_ip, ageLimit, pk_flag, kind, port, region) VALUES (@id, @name, @ip, @inner_ip, @ageLimit, @pk_flag, @kind, @port, @region)";

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", textBox1.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox2.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ip", textBox3.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inner_ip", textBox4.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ageLimit", textBox5.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pk_flag", textBox6.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kind", textBox7.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@port", textBox8.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@region", textBox9.Text);
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: You need to add more detail about what you are attempting, and possibly what errors you are getting.  The code you have in the question appears to be fine, and doesn't show anything about binary data...

Comment: @MaxVernon The problem is I don't how to make data from textbox to be inserted in sql table as binary, exmaple here ` command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", textBox1.Text);` I want to add binary

Answer (score 0):

on the ONBLUR evet of that text-box change that text into binary format

with the help of the code

```
String s = "foo";
  byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
  StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
  for (byte b : bytes)
  {
     int val = b;
     for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
     {
        binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
        val <<= 1;
     }
     binary.append(' ');
  }
  System.out.println("'" + s + "' to binary: " + binary);
```

then insert that binary data to your column

Comment: this will not work? : `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", SqlDbType.Binary, textBox3.Text);`

Answer (score 0):

Solved :
I used on SQL Query, was more easy:
`command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO server (id, name, ip, inner_ip, ageLimit, pk_flag, kind, port, region) VALUES (CONVERT(binary,@id), @name, @ip, @inner_ip, @ageLimit, @pk_flag, @kind, @port, @region)";`